# Different md5sum values of same kernel image

Tags: compilation, kernel

Two sets of compilations of same kernel sources on the same machine at different times create a vmlinuz file with different md5sum.
What could be the reason behind this?

```
OS - CentOS 6.7

gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/proc/version` pseudo-file contains a compilation timestamp. See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). That timestamp is *somewhere* inside the kernel image. So two successive compilations of the same kernel give different images.